# Issue in getting pickup point with urldecode, while Google map's distance calculation

Tags: ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

While Google map's distance calculation, the urldecode not get the pickup point

I want to calculate the distance between a two places using the Google map API.

In the following url, the **origins** value is get empty. But when I remove **+Phase+2%2C+** from the url its working fine.

Is there any problem with this **+Phase+2%2C+** in google map url?

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Perungudi+RMZ+Millenia+Business+Park+Phase+2%2C+Kodandarama+Nagar%2C+Perungudi%2C+Chennai%2C+Tamil+Nadu%2C+IndiaSholinganallur+Wipro+Technologies+CDC5%2C+S&destinations=EZ+Avenue%2C+Elcot+Sez%2C+Sholinganallur%2C+Oggiamduraipakkam%2C+Tamil+Nadu%2C+India&mode=driving&language=en&sensor=false
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with the encoding, the address simply can't be resolved(geocoded):

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3DPerungudi%20RMZ%20Millenia%20Business%20Park%20Phase%202%2C%20Kodandarama%20Nagar%2C%20Perungudi%2C%20Chennai%2C%20Tamil%20Nadu%2C%20IndiaSholinganallur%20Wipro%20Technologies%20CDC5%2C%20S